# Eliminate intermediate variable when combining here document, substitution and die

Tags: perl

Is it possible to eliminate the use of the intermediate variable `$msg` in this example?

```
($msg = <<'END_MSG') =~ s/\n//gm;
My super error message
Which happens to span over multiple lines
But that I want to print without newlines.
END_MSG
die $msg;
```

If I did not need to remove the newlines, I could do directly `die <<'END_MSG'; ...` but I have not found a way to combine these two approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With perl 5.14 or newer you can,

```
die <<'END_MSG'
My super error message
Which happens to span over multiple lines
But that I want to print without newlines.
END_MSG
=~ s/\n//gr;
```

EDIT:
or

```
die <<'END_MSG' =~ s/\n//gr
..
END_MSG
```

Comment: The `/r` modifier requires at least Perl 5.14.

Comment: Or `die <<'END_MSG' =~ s/\n//gr; ...` if you don't want to hide the `s///` down at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

`die` takes multiple arguments, so you could just do this:

```
die split /\n/, <<'END_MSG';
...
END_MSG
```